# how to connect from another PC and another connection to my sql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

just a small question i have made a code that connects me to my sql table through vb from my localhost, so if i sent this program to another one can he connect to my database ? if not then how ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this link for your referal.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1